# Modify the lapse of onItemLongClick in a listview

Tags: android, onitemlongclicklistener

I need to modify the lapse of onItemLongClick (The default duration is too fast for an old person). Can someone help me?

```
    listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // Do something
            ...
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

you cannot achieve this using the `OnItemLongClickListener`, you will need your own implementation of the `OnTouchListener` to define/determine the long click duration.

I do not have a possibility to test the code right now, but this should give you a basic idea where to start:

```
private long mTimestampDown;
private long mTimestampUp;
private final int longPressDurationMs = 2000; // 2 seconds
private boolean isLongPress = false;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
 switch (e.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      mTimestampDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
       mTimestampUp = System.currentTimeMillis();
       if(mTimestampUp - mTimestampDown > longPressDurationMs) 
         isLongPress = true;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
return isLongPress;
}
```

Your class should extend the `OnTouchListener`.

Comment: Thank you, but in this way the event is ON when ACTION_UP and not after xxxx milliseconds. Furthermore I cannot identify the line in the listview.

Comment: @EneryDome sure, the event occurs when the user releases the key, all you can do is measuring the elapsed time. If you mean the core problem is that the mentioned persons release the finger too fast - I guess you cannot differentiate clicks and long clicks. 
As for tracking the item that was long-pressed - well,  I'm not sure how to do it with the (now deprecated?) `ListView`, I use an `OnItemTouchListener` with a custom `GestureDetector` for `RecyclerViews`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `OnTouchListener`? 
Define your duration, and check touching time on `ACTION_DOWN`.

On `ACTION_UP`:

```
if  ( the time > your duration ) { 
    do the job you want 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not elegant and perfect but with 2 global variables (IsDown and position) I can resolve my problem.

```
    listview.setOnTouchListener(new AdapterView.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent e) {
            switch (e.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    setIsDown(true);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    setIsDown(false);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });

    listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            setPosition(position);

            final Handler h = new Handler();
            h.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if (getIsDown()) {


                         // Do something
                         ...


                    }
                }
            }, 1000); // milliseconds added to longpress

            return true;
        }

    });
```